# postgres: multiple regexp_replace statements - performance?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I'm trying to do a large number of regexp_replaces and I'm looking for ways to speed it up. I've attempted to test if nesting the statements is faster than passing the result to a variable and then running the next replace on the result.

I'm seeing about a 10% savings in time for the second nested example below. Is this what would be expected, and the recommended way to do multiple regexp_replaces?

Alternatively, is there something completely different I should be trying?

The third code block is an snippet of how my actual function looks.

not nested (no purpose to this, its just generating random chars for performance testing):

```
do
$$
declare 
  i record;
  _output text;
begin
  for i in 1..100000 loop
    _output = regexp_replace((SELECT string_agg(c, '')
                            FROM (SELECT c
                            FROM regexp_split_to_table(
                            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',
                             ''
                           ) c
                            ORDER BY random()
                            LIMIT 6
                           ) AS q)
     ,'A|B|C|1',' ','g');

    _output = regexp_replace(_output,' ','x','g');


  end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

nested  (no purpose to this, its just generating random chars for performance testing):

```
do
$$
declare 
  i record;
  _output text;
begin
  for i in 1..100000 loop

    _output = regexp_replace(regexp_replace((SELECT string_agg(c, '')
                            FROM (SELECT c
                            FROM regexp_split_to_table(
                            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',
                             ''
                           ) c
                            ORDER BY random()
                            LIMIT 6
                           ) AS q)
     ,'A|B|C|1',' ','g'),' ','x','g');


  end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

actual function looks like this, however there are more than two replacements and its intended to be run on tables with millions of records:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION address_appartment_cleanup_test(_input text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$

BEGIN
 _input = (SELECT regexp_replace(_input,'^APARTMENT ','APT ', 'g'));
 _input = (SELECT regexp_replace(_input,'^SUITE ','STE ', 'g'));
RETURN _input;
END;
$body$
  VOLATILE
  COST 100;


SELECT address_appartment_cleanup_test('APARTMENT 10'); -- desired output APT 10
SELECT address_appartment_cleanup_test('SUITE 10');     -- desired output STE 10
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? It *looks like* it could be simplified. Sample data and desired results would clarify that.

Comment: @GMB I've edited the post to show what the actual function looks like in the third block. Blocks 1 and two were what i used to test the difference between nesting and not nesting. The gain seemed small so I'm wondering what is recommended for this type of thing.

Comment: You may get some performance using the [REPLACE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-replace/) function instead of REGEXP_REPLACE as regexps are relative slow functions. That would have the side effect of replacing all occurrences in the source string. The 'g' flag in the regex indicates that was the intent but will never have more that 1 replacement as the pattern indicates beginning of string (^).